# How to manipulate Date object

Tags: java, date

How can I increase by day a date object? being careful of the month.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

That's a job for the [Calendar](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Calendar.html) class.

Basically

```
Calendar cal = Calendar.getInstance();
cal.setTime(myDate);
cal.add(Calendar.DATE, 1);
myDaye = cal.getTime();
```

If you're serious about Date/Time manipulation, check out [Joda-Time](http://joda-time.sourceforge.net/)

Comment: yeah, you have to use instance of Calendar class for that.

Answer (score 5):

Depends on what you mean by "increase by a day".  If you mean "increase by exactly 24 hours", then:

```
new Date(date.getTime() + 24*60*60*1000);
```

If you want to correct for the fact that not all days are 24 hours (daylight savings switchover days, for example), see the other answers.

Answer (score 2):

This is terribly difficult and that's why we should use `Calendar` for that. Otherwise you'll have to handle the different month lengths and leap years. The `Calendar` implementation can do that already.